# Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.Droid change view

Tags: c#, android-intent, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

So far, I've been unsuccessful at finding anything on this that has worked. I'm trying to change the current view from a class in the .droid namespace to another in the same namespace.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(viewclass));
```

Is what seems to be half correct. The biggest problem is *this* as I cannot do that from the droid, I get the following error:

```
Cannot convert from App.Droid.CustomMapRenderer to Android.Context.Context
```

Solution:

```
var intent= new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(ViewClass));
Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The biggest problem is this as I cannot do that from the droid, I get the following error:

From the error message. You are creating an Intent inside a renderer(`CustomMapRenderer`). Thus `this` refers to an instance of `CustomMapRenderer`, but to create an intent the first argument should be a `Context`.

So to fix the problem, you need to retrieve the current context in certain way,
For example, you can try `Intent intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(viewclass));`

Comment: Yes, thank you. With your suggestion I got it through this     `Android.App.Application.Context` to get the current context.